# TestNG in Eclipse: Avoid test class files in output folder

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

How can I manage to avoid having the class files compiled from my TestNG test classes in my output directory? Wanting to test doesn't mean I want to deploy these classes on my server...

Comment: Are you deploy to the server from Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse to deploy to the server, you can control what is included in the deployed artifact.  Under 'Deployment Assembly' of the project properties, remove the folder that contains the test classes.

Another possibility is to change individual output folders under the Java Build Path of the project's properties:

1. In the Source tab, check 'Allow output folder for source folders'.
2. For the source folder containing the test files, change the Output folder to something other then the default output folder.

With that the test sources will be compiled to a separate directory.

HTH